# Intellitrace and Windows Services

Tags: c#, .net, intellitrace

I'm trying to run IntelliTrace on a Windows Service, but encountering some issues.
I've (generally) tried the steps that are detailed here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msaffer/archive/2011/02/23/using-intellitrace-with-services.aspx.

I've tried VS 2013 Update 3 IntelliTrace download (from Microsoft) and also the new collector thats included with VS 2015 Enterprise RC. Both respond the same.

So:

Test service, registered, running as an administrator (so it's not access rights).
An Environment key has been created with the following values:

```
COR_ENABLE_PROFILING=1
VSLOGGERCPLAN=C:\Intellitrace14\collection_plan.myplan.trace.xml
COR_PROFILER={AAAAAA70-DFED-4CB4-A1D6-920F51E9674A}
```

(This is the CLSID that is registered for 2015 RC it seems)

When I start the service, it fires up but in the Event Log I get:

```
The profiler has requested that the CLR instance not load the profiler into this process.
```

I've tried with both a 32-bit and 64-bit compiled service (and the relevant IntelliTrace being registered).

I know that Windows services aren't realy a supported target for IntelliTrace, but it did used to work with 2010 etc -- has something really changed for the current versions or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a blog post that explains how to collect data from a windows service in production using IntelliTrace. http://bit.ly/1bTfcIO

If you have any issues following this guide you can also contact me directly at angelos.petropoulos@microsoft.com

On a related note, here is also the announcement that IntelliTrace in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise now also supports attaching to a running process. http://bit.ly/1bT1Psn This means you can also attach to a running windows service without restarting it.

Answer (score 1):

This post is a bit old and you may have figured it out already... but I had the same issue and, after much searching, a bit of screaming and a lot of trial and error, I finally hit on the problem.  The environment setting is very sensitive to extra spaces.  Once I cleaned out spaces around or next to the equal signs and from the end of each line, IntelliTrace worked for me.